# NuGet Package Manager Console won't open

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I am new to asp.net.
I am following a tutorial on how to connect the database with my MVC application.
I need to open Console Package Manager to do some migrations, but it won't open it.
It does not show any error or message, just ignores it.
Also, that happens when I try to run the terminal.
I tried re-installing the packages and restarting Visual Studio and also my PC, but it does not help. I have no idea what the problem could be.
Any help or suggestion would be very appreciated, thanks!

Comment: The panel may have been un-docked, and could be hiding on another monitor or behind another window.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of your screen after you want to open?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you care about running the migrations, you can do so, by using `.Net Core CLI` in terminal instead of Package Manager Console. [See examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli)

`dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate` == `Add-Migration InitialCreate`

Regarding window being gone - maybe it is appearing, but not where you expect it to. Have you searched through whole UI, by default it could be shown next to Output in the bottom bar.

Comment: Yes, it was hidden, thanks!

Comment: If it was helpful an upvote or accepting the answer would be nice :)